# SQL query on parents and relations

Tags: sql

so, recently i attended an interview where they asked the question like this,
there are 2 tables with parents and id in 1 table and relations between the id's on the 2nd table and we need to output based on the relations table the name of child father and mother .

**input table parents:**

```
id  name
1   yogi
2   sidda
4   arpitha
5   sushma
6   navya
7   divya
8   sanju
9   ashwin
10  chetu
11  seena
12  vindi
```

**input table relations:**

```
child_id parent_id
4   1
4   2
5   10
5   6
7   8
7   9
11  12
11  13
```

The SQL is

```
select child,p2.name1, from parents p2 join 
( select p1.name1 as child,r1.p_id,r1.c_id,p1.id1 from parents p1 join (select * from parents join relations on p_id=id1) r1 on p1.id1=r1.c_id) r2 on p2.id1=p_id;
```

**which is giving me outlook like:**

```
child parents
arpita yogi
arpita sidda 
sushma chetu 
sushma navya 
divya sanju
divya ashwin 
seena vindi 
seena varshini
```

**My expected output is:**

```
child   father  mother
arpitha yogi    sidda
sushma  chetu   navya
divya   sanju   ashwin
seena   vindi   varshini
```

this looks a lot like normalization question.

Comment: How can you differentiate father and mother? Is there any tags or column for the Gender in the tables?

Comment: Hi Dinesh, no , there were no tags for gender, but i guess whatever would be the first row would be the correct one,

Comment: I tried self join as well using this query:
select r.c_id as child,r.p_id as father,r1.p_id as mother from relations r join relations r1 on r.c_id=r1.c_id and r.p_id<>r1.p_id  ;

Answer (score 0):

Not a great interview question as there's no way to solidly differentiate between mother and father - it's setting up for failure. It seems the first name is the father consistently so an approach using row number in a CTE would work

```
WITH c AS (
 SELECT
 T1.name
 ,T2.p_id
 ,T3.name as p_name
 ,row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY T2.c_id ORDER BY T2.p_id) AS row_no

 FROM
 names T1
 INNER JOIN link T2
 ON T1.id = T2.c_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN names AS T3
 ON T2.p_id = T3.id
)

SELECT 
T1.name AS c_name
,IS_NULL(T2.p_name,'none') AS f_name
,IS_NULL(T3.p_name,'none') AS m_name

FROM 
c AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN c AS T2
ON T1.name = T2.name AND T2.row_no = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN c AS T3
ON T1.name = T3.name AND T3.row_no = 2
```